# Debug remoto em ambientes isolados

Tags: java, tomcat, debug

Trabalho em uma empresa fazendo correções de bugs. Alguns clientes implantam o sistema em computadores da sua rede interna, por isso, não é possível fazer debug remoto.

Os computadores dos clientes normalmente possuem acesso à Internet.

Gostaria de saber se há alguma ferramenta que permitiria fazer debug remoto.

Se eu criasse um VPN com `OpenVpn`, resolveria o meu problema?

Comment: Acredito que seja necessário realizar a liberação de acesso externo no seu banco de dados e fazer o direcionamento de porta do seu modem para a porta do banco de dados. Se você conseguir acessar o banco externamente, você irá conseguir debugar a aplicação na sua máquina. Eu faço isso para um banco de dados que está na amazon e funciona perfeitamente!

Comment: O projeto está implantado em outra rede. Não teria como depurar localmente.

Comment: O projeto pode estar implantado em outra rede, mas você possui o código fonte do mesmo não? Altere os dados de conexão apontando para o banco de dados remoto e caso o mesmo esteja disponível para o acesso externo, você irá conseguir fazer este processo sem problemas.

Comment: Você quer debugar incluindo o banco de dados, ou só o código mesmo apontando para um banco qualquer?

Comment: só o código fonte independente de banco.

Answer (score 2):

Minha sugestão para você é a seguinte:

1) Instale o Eclipse em alguma estação local (servidor de internet, servidor auxiliar ou na própria estação do cliente.)

2) Para o procedimento acima e conexão remota com o cliente, utilize o Supremo(Cópia FreeWare do TeamViewer) ou o TeamViewer(Freeware apenas para "uso pessoal"): http://www.majorgeeks.com/mg/getmirror/supremo_remote_desktop,1.html

3) Na estação do cliente, inicie o sistema executando o catalina, caso ele não esteja configurado para o modo debug: 
        **catalina.bat jpda start**

4) Siga os passos deste link para debugar através do eclipse:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835612/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse

Comment: O problema é que não poderei depurar localmente porque o projeto está implantado em um servidor que está em outra rede. E o problema de depurar no cliente é que teria que copiar o código-fonte em um local onde outras pessoas acessam.

Comment: http://ptcomputador.com/Networking/virtual-networks/80912.html -< Este tópico explica de modo facil como habilitar a VPN no clientes com windows 7. se fizer isso, pode acessar localmente e conectar no tomcat sem precisar copiar o codigo fonte